# Gateway vs Dialup API backend API's

Tags: api, credit-card

*Need to access Dialup terminal transnational history*

I'm a software engineer and thus far my world has been on the internet. So any payment processing I've ever doen has been through Gateways (Auth.net, SecureNet, ...etc) However I have a new project that requires me to deal with physical terminals. Some terminals that are linked to WiFi or Ethernet are exactly the same they just go through the gateway and and the backend API continue to work. Dialup terminals are apparently different and skip a gateway all together.

**Does anyone know how I can get a dialup terminal's transactional history via some backend API**?

Comment: This will be entirely dependent on the device; you will need to ask the issuing bank.

Answer (score 1):

So I called up the gateway (securenet) and they are telling me that I wouldnt get terminal transaction history via the API. This was confusing because the API documentation states if there was a pin pad on site which would imply a terminal.

I also called up a terminal programming firm. They assured me that even if they wrote custom software to the terminal it still wouldnt have access to the transaction unless it was the processing software itself.

so the answer is I'm SOL